# 100% height input-field and align text vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, css

Maybe a duplicate but I did not found a question with a similar problem.

Ok, I've to create a `100%` height input field that centers the text vertically and horizontally. The problem is that if I set the `line-height` to `window`-width the **cursor** gets the same size in Chrome.

Any ideas how to center the text without `line-height`?

```
input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0
}
```

Just to set the `line-height`:

```
$('input').css({
    lineHeight: $(window).height() + 'px'
});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/G9uVw/

**Update**

It seems that the question needs to be changed. The problem is that **oldIE** doesn't center the text, but all other browsers do. So the new question is, how can we check if a browser supports this `auto-center`-`feature?! (Since we know that`ua`-sniffing is evil, I don't want to check for a particular browser...)

**Update2**

It seems that this is a bug in webkit: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47284

Comment: I removed the JavaScript lineheight and the text was centered.  I'm using Chrome Version 27.0.1453.110.

Comment: @RyanE Yeah, sure! The centering the text in chrome is not problem. But in oldIe for example. I'm playing around in ff and opera now.

Comment: ...also chrome on android

Comment: @3rror404 Okay, it seems that this occurs only on oldIE. But I hate `ua`-sniffing!

Comment: Does this work?  http://jsfiddle.net/xqfqM/

Comment: @RyanE Nope, doesn't center the text in oldIE. BTW: `vertical-align` is only for `block`-elements ;)

Comment: Darn.  What version of IE?

Comment: @RyanE The *stupid* IE8...

Comment: Have you seen this question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412696/how-to-vertical-align-text-on-this-input-box-for-ie    It looks like it has a solution for the large cursor on chrome.  Or is the large cursor an issue on IE as well?

Comment: @RyanE Yep, already seen. I think it's a problem in problem in the *webkit*-core. And should be ignored, since it will fixed soon, so I hope ;)

Comment: This answer also claims to have a fix for the cursor issue in chrome, maybe it could help?  The fiddle looks fine to me on chrome, anyway:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10717364/1181886

Comment: @RyanE Yeah, it's a known issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47284 (http://jsbin.com/avefi/3) I'll ignore this for now. However, thanks alot for you interest & time :-*

Comment: @yckart thanks for the useful question, had the same issue. I ended up using `top-padding` & `bottom-padding` as a work around, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717294/text-field-cursor-issue-in-chrome/26426266#26426266

Answer (score 0):

Try this, should align vertically:

```
input {

    //// vertical align
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    ////

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0
}
```

Not sure if the height: 100% will avoid the job, try it without height: 100% if it doesn't work. If that's the case, maybe the solution is to calculate the height everytime with javascript/jquery.